# Is there a way to load a memory mapped file into memory at once

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a large binary file (about 1 GB) that I want to process sequentially. I'm using a memory mapped file to access the file. Is there a way to tell Windows to swap in the whole file as soon as possible? Currently, it looks as if windows is only loading a single page each time a page fault occurs which results in very slow processing.

Comment: Why not just load the entire file into memory yourself?

Comment: Your analysis of the bottleneck sounds implausible. In any case memory mapped file is gross overkill here. Sequential file processing is made for streams. You want a stream that maintains its own buffer so that you can hit the OS read function in large chunks.

Comment: @Steve-o: Many reasons: I want to modify part of the file - that's much easier if it's a mapped file. Second reading the file at once would mean waiting until the whole file is in memory before processing it. By using a MMF, I can start processing while it's still being read (possible with async IO, but much harder to do). Third, in case there *isn't* enough RAM, reading the file completely would mean lots of very inefficient swapping.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I could do stream processing, but it would be much more complex to code and less efficient, if I can find a way to load the MMF as fast as possible. But that has nothing to do with the question, so I didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: It would not be any more complex, and certainly would not be less efficient. Anyway, I question seriously your diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: [The Old New Thing - How do I prefetch data into my memory-mapped file?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/01/10312874.aspx) has some discussion (also note the comments)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You can't expect me to give you all the details of 200kloc application in a simple API question. I just described the 0.1% that are relevant to the question. You'll have to take my word that solving my problem with ordinary sequential file access would be much more complex, and probably less efficient.

Comment: Raymond is offering exactly the same solution as Steve-o. And what's more his preferred option is standard file access.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Again: if you only wanted to sequentially process a file from end to end, then reading it sequentially would probably be the best solution. But that's *not* all my application does. It also modifies the files far faster than the HDD can write, later does some random-access anywhere in the file, also some sharing between processes. But all these things work as they should. The only thing that's slow is one (rare) edge case where the file is not mapped in memory already and has to processed completely. Hence the question.

Comment: When you said "I have a large binary file (about 1 GB) that I want to process sequentially", I though you meant that you had a large binary file that you wanted to process sequentially. I guess I misunderstood you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, problem. There's always a trade-off when asking a question: Give too much information and people tell you to simplify the question, remove irrelevant information. Do that and people tell you that's overkill, such a simple problem can be solved much easier.

Comment: @nikie It is annoying when people try to tell you that your problem isn't a problem and shouldn't be answered. This happens to me on occasion. I am interested in prefetching also because I want to asynchronously read a file while processing it, and the logic to do that is complicated. It would be nice to use the preexisting OS facilities that are designed to do such an operation already rather than a complex roll-your-own implementation. (I have been on both sides of the fence of question asking and both sides think the other is an idiot, when likely neither are.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really surprised nobody's mentioned [PrefetchVirtualMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh780543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI PrefetchVirtualMemory(
  _In_  HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR NumberOfEntries,
  _In_  PWIN32_MEMORY_RANGE_ENTRY VirtualAddresses,
  _In_  ULONG Flags
);
```

Here are some other links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx
- [Performance of Win32 memory mapped files vs. CRT fopen/fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980035/performance-of-win32-memory-mapped-files-vs-crt-fopen-fread)
- http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files

Personally, I have no idea whether any of this is a Good Idea or not for your application.  But sure - try it, and see if it helps!

IMHO ..

Comment: OK - Here's a neat hack that might help: [Win32 Custom Prefetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562581/custom-prefetch)

Answer (score 1):

When you wish to force a chunk of the file to be paged in to memory, call `ReadFile` using the  file handle that you used to create the file mapping.